# How to combine two lists in a non standard way in Python

Tags: python, list

I've got the following two lists:

```
a = ['A-B', 'A-D', 'B-C', 'B-D', 'B-E', 'C-E', 'D-E', 'D-F', 'E-F', 'E-G', 'F-G']
b = ['7', '5', '8', '9', '7', '5', '15', '6', '8', '9', 11]
```

I want to convert these lists into one like this:

```
[ ("A", "B", 7), ("A", "D", 5), ("B", "C", 8), ("B", "D", 9), ("B", "E", 7), ("C", "E", 5), ("D", "E", 15), ("D", "F", 6), ("E", "F", 8), ("E", "G", 9), ("F", "G", 11)]
```

The problem is that the first list needs to be split and the merged into the second, with a tuple as the output. What's the pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a = ['A-B', 'A-D', 'B-C', 'B-D', 'B-E', 'C-E', 'D-E', 'D-F', 'E-F', 'E-G', 'F-G']    
>>> b = ['7', '5', '8', '9', '7', '5', '15', '6', '8', '9', 11]
>>> [x.split('-') + [int(y)] for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[['A', 'B', 7], ['A', 'D', 5], ['B', 'C', 8], ['B', 'D', 9], ['B', 'E', 7], ['C', 'E', 5], ['D', 'E', 15], ['D', 'F', 6], ['E', 'F', 8], ['E', 'G', 9], ['F', 'G', 11]]
```

If you really need a tuple just use the `tuple(...)` constructor eg.

```
tuple(x.split('-') + [int(y)])
```

Comment: I want elements inside list to be tuple not a list.

Comment: then do `[tuple(a) for a in the_results`]

Comment: Thanks mate. I will accept your answer whenever I can.

Comment: @user2032220 Do you only use single characters? If so you could use the solution by `@antitrust`

Comment: No, that's just a example. I use name of cities with more than one character.

Answer (score 2):

avoiding the split,

```
[(k[0][0],k[0][-1],k[1]) for k in zip(a,b)]
```

or even

```
[(x[0],x[-1],y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Comment: +1 good idea (assuming only single characters), add `int(k[1])` as well. Also this would look much nicer if you had `for x, y in zip(a, b)`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['A-B', 'A-D', 'B-C', 'B-D', 'B-E', 'C-E', 'D-E', 'D-F', 'E-F', 'E-G', 'F-G']
b = ['7', '5', '8', '9', '7', '5', '15', '6', '8', '9', 11]

mylist=[]
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    tmp= x.split('-')
    mylist.append((tmp[0],tmp[1],int(y)))
```

mylist= [('A', 'B', 7), ('A', 'D', 5), ('B', 'C', 8), ('B', 'D', 9), ('B', 'E',7), ('C', 'E', 5), ('D', 'E', 15), ('D', 'F', 6), ('E', 'F', 8), ('E','G', 9), ('F', 'G', 11)]

Comment: Two things: Don't use `list` as a name, it just gets confused with the built-in. Second, the integers should be integers, and not strings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [ tuple(val.split('-') + [int(b[idx])]) for idx, val in enumerate(a) ]
[('A', 'B', 7), ('A', 'D', 5), ('B', 'C', 8)]
```

But it is really stupid, there is no error handling.